# Call Hangfire Job (Recurring Job) from external API

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I have been using Hang-fire in our project but had a question, Can i call a hangfire Recurring Job from an API?

For Example: 
http://devmyproject.com/projectname/recurring is the url for Hangfire web application to get recurring job.
Now from my webApi project i want to call this Url and invoke a Job to run.
Is this Possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In The HangFire Project i added an end points to make it an API to get the Requests and then run the Hangfire job. I added Fire and Forget Job to run the HangFire job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can certainly perform hangfire functions by calling an API. Here is the function for creating a Hangfire job as listed on the front page of [hangfire site](https://www.hangfire.io/).

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"),
Cron.Daily);
```

The URL you call should be an endpoint which you can pass parameters to. Then if hangfire is set up correctly it should be like any other application.

Comment: Can i call from API to the Hang-fire Recurring Job?

Example: MyWebAPI/Post/{firehangfire} -> this should call hangfire myRecurring Job. Can you provide me with example.

Comment: You will need some kind of API on the hangfire side to field the requests. I dont know the structure of your application but you will need an endpoint that accepts http requests on  MyWebAPI/Post/{firehangfire} which should be on the same project as hangfire